# Attribute represented in a JSON schema whose type could be of two different types

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm writting a JSON Schema, but I have a little problem. I've a JSON file, where attibute can be of two different types, let's see an example of the JSON file where the trouble has appeared.

The JSON file:

```
"predicates" : [
        {
        "predicate":{ "text": "STATE == TRUE", "type" : "P" }
        },
        {
        "predicate":"None"
        }
    ]
```

Predicate can be a Object type or a string with the value None, so, how would be represented in a JSON Schema?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

JSON Schema `type` keyword accepts an array of values in addition to a single string.

Your schema would look like...

```
{
  "properties": {
    "predicates": {
      "items": {
        "properties": {
          "predicate": {
            "type": [
              "string",
              "object"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can test it by changing one of the types to something else. Here's a playground with this schema: https://jsonschema.dev/s/2NcC2

Answer (score 0):

You want the `anyOf` keyword. It allows you to give multiple schemas. If any of the `anyOf` schemas are valid, the `anyOf` is valid.

```
{
  "anyOf": [
    { "const": "None" },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "text": { "type": "string" },
        "type": { "type": "string" }
      },
      "required": ["text", "type"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's and additional reference, https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html#anyof